# Is $\neg q \equiv \neg q \lor p \equiv \neg q \lor \neg p$ a theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

So I tried solving a theorem, and ended up with the following answer:
$$\neg q \equiv \neg q  \lor p \equiv  \neg q  \lor \neg p$$

Can a theorem be true even if proven with a negative variable? Doesn't $ \neg q$ render the theorem false?

I would have been pretty confident if I had:
$$ q \equiv  q  \lor p \equiv   q  \lor \neg p$$
as an answer, because the theorem would be proven true because $q$ is true in all cases.

Thank you for your answer.. I might have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The equivalences $\neg q \equiv \neg q \vee p$ is justified by disjunctive addition (they are logically equivalent via truth table). Similarly for the second equivalence.  
If $\neg q$ is true, then $\neg q \vee p$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

$$\neg q \equiv \neg q  \lor p \equiv  \neg q  \lor \neg p$$

is a generalized biconditional with three terms. Generalized biconditionals are true if and only if an even number of its terms are false.

Now, if $q$ is true, then the first term $\neg q$ is definitely false, and of the other two terms $\neg q \lor p$ and $\neg q \lor \neg p$ exactly one will be true, since with $q$ being true, their truth-value solely depends on $p$. So, tow terms will be false, meaning that the statement is true.

On the other hand, if $q$ is false, then all three terms are true, so again the statement is true.

So, yes, the statement is a logical theorem.

Note that the same reasoning (just with the cases for $q$ being true and false flipped) would also show that your second statement

$$q \equiv q  \lor p \equiv  q  \lor \neg p$$

is also a theorem.